# Python Regexp for extracting tags and words

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, tokenize

I have the following string:

```
str1 = "I/TAG1 like/TAG2 red/TAG3 apples/TAG3 ./TAG4"
```

And I have two lists in python

```
tokens = []
tags = []
```

My desired output would be:

```
tokens = ['I', 'like', 'red', 'apples', '.']
tags = ['TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'TAG3', 'TAG4']
```

I am trying to use a regexp like this one:

```
r"\w*\/"
```

But that extracts the words with the slash, i.e I/. How can I get the desired output, at least for tokens (get everything before the /)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([\w.]+)/([\w.]+)', str1)

[('I', 'TAG1'), ('like', 'TAG2'), ('red', 'TAG3'), ('apples', 'TAG3'), ('.', 'TAG4')]
```

**Code:**

```
>>> tags=[]
>>> vals=[]
>>> for m in re.findall(r'([\w.]+)/([\w.]+)', str1):
...     tags.append(m[0])
...     vals.append(m[1])
...

>>> print tags
['I', 'like', 'red', 'apples', '.']

>>> print vals
['TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'TAG3', 'TAG4']
```

Comment: One last question, what I have to do if I want to also extract words like these: mt./gal/hr/TAG5, 1/2/TAG5 ? (The tag is always after the last /)

Comment: ok use this regex then `r'(\S+)/([\w.]+)'` instead of `r'([\w.]+)/([\w.]+)'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `str.split()` by space and by slash. Then calling `zip()` to pipe the output into two separate lists:

```
>>> tokens, tags = zip(*[item.split("/") for item in str1.split()])
>>> tokens
('I', 'like', 'red', 'apples', '.')
>>> tags
('TAG1', 'TAG2', 'TAG3', 'TAG3', 'TAG4')
```